# How to prevent vim-jsx from mangling my indentation?

Tags: formatting, file-formats, plugin-vim-jsx

Looks like the issue is caused by `vim-jsx`.

Given:

```
  componentDidMount: function() { ▐$.ajax({ });
```

I press enter to move $.ajax onto a new line and the top line folds as well:

```
componentDidMount: function() { 
$.ajax({ });
```

This is really annoying as I have to correct indentation in both lines now.

Also then I do `==` it collapses all indentation as well.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: This looks like a bug.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem like valid JSX?

Answer (score 2):

According to [mxw/vim-jsx#63](https://github.com/mxw/vim-jsx/issues/63) there may have been a bug in pangloss' vim-javascript that triggered this issue.  It doesn't reproduce on the current (circa 2016 Feb 8) master branches for vim-jsx and its required dependency [vim-javascript](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript).