# Using single quotes blows up syntax formatting in .js

Tags: indentation, formatting, filetype-javascript

Just noticed that using single quotes in javascript blows up automatic formatting sometimes:

See the `public/sass/*.sass` line:

Double quotes:

```
gulp.task('compile-sass', function(){
  gulp
    .src("public/sass/*.sass")
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({ indentedSyntax: true, errLogToConsole: true }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/stylesheets'));
});
```

Single quotes:

```
gulp.task('compile-sass', function(){
  gulp
    .src('public/sass/*.sass')
                       .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
                       .pipe(sass({ indentedSyntax: true, errLogToConsole: true }))
                       .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
                       .pipe(gulp.dest('public/stylesheets'));
                       });
```

In fact I was noticing some peculiarities of automatic indenter before, but only now I was able to pinpoint it.

Questions are usual - what gives and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using plain JS? OR JSX? (asking because you [previously asked a question about indentation with JSX](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3228/how-to-prevent-vim-jsx-from-mangling-my-indentation))

Comment: Plain `.js`, this is `Gulpfile.js`

Comment: Are you using Vim's built in JS syntax or the `vim-javascript plugin`?

Comment: No additional plugins, didn't even think about installing one. Think it worth trying?